# Package inputenc Error: Unicode char èse (U+E0)

Tags: errors, unicode, input-encodings, texniccenter

I'm writing a report on Latex and when I build my file, I got 1 error and I have no idea what the problem is.
[image]

Here the package that I load at the beginning of the document and all my files are save in utf8 format :

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you load `inputenc` with option `[utf8]`, and is your file really encoded in utf8?

Comment: Hi Bernard, I just modify my post to include more details. Yes I load inputenc with option [utf8] and I think my files are encoded in utf8.

Comment: I asked the second question because it already happened me to have downloaded files I thought utf8-encoded, but which were not, and converting them later, with a mix of utf8 and non-utf8 characters resulted in a mess. You should check if your file is really utf8-encoded. TeXmaker, for instance, will warn you if it's not.

Comment: Strange. `E0` doesn't map to `è` but `à`.

Comment: Rather posting images of the code can you post the actual code. This way people and cut and paste it to try it out. Ideally, you should post a complete [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). This is a minimal length compliable latex file that demonstrates your problem. Cutting your code down to a MWE often reveals what the problem is and, even if it doesn't, it clarifies for others what the issue is and so makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: almost certainly the document is in latin1 not utf8 encoding so the utf8 decoder specified by `inputenc` is confused.

Comment: @n.r. the number shown is pretty meaningless, latex isn't doing a lot of error checking here and is trying to decode the three (single byte) characters èse as three bytes of a UTF-8 encoding but that isn't a legal UTF-8 string so it just falls out as some random codepoint.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I save all my files in latin1 and load latin1{inpuntenc} and things are going well now. I just wonder when you save a text file in UTF8 format with a text  editor , does all the wrong characters get skip/deleted or converted? Do you know a proper way to save your file in utf8 and be sure that all the characters are encoded in utf8?

Comment: if you use Emacs, and set the file encoding to utf-8 for example using ``-*- coding: utf-8; -*-`` at top of file, Emacs will complain when you try to save the file if any character can not be correctly encoded. But this is not the case for `é`, `ç` etc... which are handled without hiccups. More often is when you have a utf-8 encoded file and try to save it as latin-1. Or when you copy paste into latin-1 buffer from a PDF, which often generates characters (apostrophes) not in the latin-1 encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

zzz èse zzz

\end{document}
```

If you take the above file and save it in latin-1 (iso-8859-1) encoding then it produces the error below matching your screenshot. If you save it in UTF-8 which is the encoding that has been declared to LaTeX then it runs without error.

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char �se (U+E0)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.7 zzz �se
            zzz
?
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers; I have solved my problem. It was some foreign characters in my bilbiography file. I use Zotoro to manage my bibliography and I used to automatically import reference from website to zotero.I include my bibliography in my report by exporting it directly from zotero in bibtex format.
Considering  the references come from different website, it seems like some reference have characters that weren't supported;

To find them, I use notepad++ to search non-ASCII character in my bibliography file, and I find some characters, mainly on foreign authors names; 
I also changed the encoding of all my files from utf8 to latin1 and load [latin1]{inputenc}.  Things work fine now.

I just don't get why latin1 in working better than utf8. I'm on windows.

Comment: utf8 will work as well as latin1 (and is better option going forward) but you have to ensure all files are in that format (bibtex though by default  can't really handle either and wants `\'e`) but the error showed that you had files in latin1 declared as utf-8